# Computing the adjoint of a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am taking an linear algebra class and we are on inner product space. I have a question that wants us to evaluate $T^*$ at a given vector. This is not a homework question, it is a textbook question, specifically question **3c in 6.3** of **Linear Algebra by Friedberg, Insel, Spence (pg 366)**. I will it write out though:

> $V=P_1(R)$ (the set of polynomials with degree $\leq 1$ with real coefficients) with $\langle f,g\rangle=\int_{-1}^1f(t)g(t)dt,$ $T(f)=f'+3f.$ Compute $T^*(f(t))$ where $f(t)=4-2t$.

I know the answer (it's in the textbook) but I am not sure how to obtain the solution. It's my understanding that since $V$ is finite-dimensional we know there is an adjoint and that for all $f,g\in P_1(R)$ $\langle T(g),f\rangle=\langle g,T^*(f)\rangle$. I tried setting $f=4-2t$ and I thought maybe set $g=1$ to make my computation easier but I don't think I am getting this right. I also decided to take the standard basis for $P_1(R)$ and used Gram-Schmidt to obtain an orthonormal basis $\gamma = \{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}x\}$. I am not really sure what to do next, like do I need to calculate the exact adjoint map or something. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** I figured out based on the comment made by darij grinberg. I used the fact that $\langle T(g),f\rangle=\langle g,T^*(f)\rangle$ where $g=1$ and $g=t$ and setting $T^*(f) = a+bt$ and figuring out $a$ and $b$ and then using that to compute $T^*(4-2t)$.

Comment: What does $P_1\left(R\right)$ mean? Polynomials of degree $\leq 1$ with real coefficients?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry exactly @darijgrinberg

Comment: The simplest way to compute $T^*(f)$ is probably to set $T^*(f) = a + bt$ with unknown constants $a$ and $b$, and then solve the system of the two linear equations $\left<T(g), f\right> = \left<g, T^*(f)\right>$ for $g = 1$ and $g = t$. (You have to rewrite these equations as explicit linear equations in $a$ and $b$, but you can do this, since the bilinear form is given as an easily computable integral.)

Comment: Thanks @darijgrinberg I will try that out, but since I don't know $T^*$ explicitly will that lead to issues? But I will try this right now and see what I get!

Comment: No, just rewrite $T^*(f) = a + bt$ every time you encounter $T^*(f)$.

Comment: Oh, my mistake I read your comment wrong! Thank you, let me try that.